# UIReferenceLibraryViewController cannot be presented as popup (always covers full screen)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiviewcontroller, popup

The following Swift 3 code (credit to [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-popover-menus-using-uipopoverpresentationcontroller)) creates a `UIAlertController` and successfully presents it as a popup from a `CGRect` co-ordinate on iPad, via the [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller) API:

```
func popUpToSelectTheLanguage(){
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Set expected language...", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "English", style: .default, handler: { (action) in /* Action to take */ }))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "French", style: .default, handler: { (action) in /* Action to take */ }))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

    let popover = ac.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.sourceView = view
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 64, height: 64)
    present(ac, animated: true)
}
```

However, when trying to present a different `UIViewController` as a popup, [UIReferenceLibraryViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller) (the system's mono/bi-lingual dictionary), it covers the whole screen rather than appearing as a popup.

```
func popUpTheDictionary(){
    let dic = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: "hi" as String)

    let popover = dic.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.sourceView = view
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 64, height: 64)
    present(dic, animated: true)
}
```

What's the problem here? Is further setup of the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` required, or is it simply locked against being presented as a popup?

My target is iOS 10.2, Universal; building for iPad Pro (12.9 inch).

If there is no way to solve this, I would equally accept any answer that provides the code needed to present the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` as a popover via another library (bonus points if it works as a popover on iPhone as well as iPad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.popover`.

```
func popUpTheDictionary(){
    let dic = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: "hi" as String)
    dic.modalPresentationStyle = .popover // add this

    let popover = dic.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.sourceView = view
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 64, height: 64)
    present(dic, animated: true)
}
```

`UIAlertController` does this for you since it is always a popover.

Comment: When I add your suggested line, it throws an NSGenericException: `'UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7fe4124a6700>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'`. It seems to be having problems unwrapping popover to set the sourceView. This may be related to the race condition mentioned in [Configuring a Popover for Display](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller). Can't seem to find a way around it; any ideas?

Comment: Note: I have tried moving the `present()` call to before the configuration of the popover, as suggested in the documentation I linked above, but to no success. Also, when I try force-unwrapping the popover, it immediately fails, so it may suggest some issue there.

Comment: Try accessing the `view` property of `dic` before accessing `dic.popoverPresentationController`.

Comment: I just tried adding the line `let hailmary = dic.view` immediately after the line declaring `dic`. It didn't make a difference (nor in combination with `present()` being in any of all the possible positions); same error message each time. Is that what you had in mind by accessing the `view` property?

Comment: Do it after setting `dic.modalPresentationStyle`.

Comment: Nope, still throws the same error. Also tried unwrapping the view property during the access (`let hailmary = dic.view!`), but again, no difference.

Comment: Okay, looks like the problem was merely that I'd blindly placed your suggested line `dic.modalPresentationStyle = .popover` under the line that instantiates the popover rather than the line that instantiates the UIPopoverPresentationController. Sorry for the red herring. Appears to be working now; very excited!

Comment: Thanks - really struggled with this