# Swift 4: No such module 'CoreServices.DictionaryServices'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-services

I was reading an article that talks about Core Services and decided to use one of them. I import Core Services and add the library on XCode, but it doesn't work.

Sample code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreServices.DictionaryServices

func define(_ word: String) -> String? {
    let nsstring = word as NSString
    let cfrange = CFRange(location: 0, length: nsstring.length)

    guard let definition = DCSCopyTextDefinition(nil, nsstring, cfrange) else {
        return nil
    }

    return String(definition.takeUnretainedValue())
}

define("apple") // "apple | ˈapəl | noun 1 the round fruit of a tree..."
```

It gives a "no such module" error when I import it. I also look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices) but there is no explanation for how to implement and use it.

## The Solution:

Thanks to people who answered below my question, I made a little research and found the solution. Apparently, I can use the iOS dictionary by calling the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`, but the Apple documentation says that we should not use this making for a dictionary app. It is obvious that it is not sufficient to make a dictionary app because it uses its own `ViewController` and is not customizable.

Here is the sample working code:

```
 let dic = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: textLabelOutlet.text as! String)
        dic.modalPresentationStyle = .popover // add this

        let popover = dic.popoverPresentationController
        popover?.sourceView = view
        popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 64, height: 64)
        present(dic, animated: true)
```

Source: [UIReferenceLibraryViewController cannot be presented as popup (always covers full screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219587/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller-cannot-be-presented-as-popup-always-covers-ful)

Comment: You can't access the Define feature's data but you can make use of the UI as one of the below link's answers states using: `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`. Another way: you would probably need licensing/permission to get it by Apple but if it's a personal app you could harness the `.dictionary` files on macOS decrypt the data (there are libraries to do this) and use the dictionary entries. These dictionary files are the same ones used by the `Define` feature in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

`CoreServices` may be available on all platforms but `DictionaryServices` seems to be available on macOS only.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1446842-dcscopytextdefinition

SDK lists only: `macOS 10.5+`

Answer (score 1):

`CoreServices.DictionaryServices` is a framework of OS X, not of iOS.

you could click `CoreServices.DictionaryServices`, and see the page in a mac app project.

```
/*
    DictionaryServices.h
    DictionaryServices framework

*/

/*!
    @typedef    DCSDictionaryRef
    @abstract   Opaque CF object that represents a dictionary file
*/
public class DCSDictionary {
}


@available(OSX 10.5, *)
public func DCSGetTermRangeInString(_ dictionary: DCSDictionary?, _ textString: CFString, _ offset: CFIndex) -> CFRange
```

Comment: But there is a definition feature on ios. So how does that feature work? Is there any framework similar to dictionary services for ios?

Comment: check  Access iOS dictionary programmatically .     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419940/access-ios-dictionary-programmatically